# struggling to understand JSON Parsing via PHP

Tags: php, json

not sure what I'm doing wrong here but i have my Json string and I'm trying to get the values to print out in the IF statement
i.e:
`63,52,55`

here is my code:

```
$jayjay = '{"items":{"cID":"63","qty":"2"},"items":{"cID":"52","qty":"1"},"items":{"cID":"55","qty":"1"}}';
echo $jayjay;
$obj = json_decode($jayjay, TRUE);
for($i=0; $i<=count($obj['items']); $i++) {

     echo $obj['items'][$i]['cID'];
     echo ",";
}
```

but the output is just blank and i cant figure out why

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Often when that happens it is because of a syntax error in the JSON data. Check the results of `json_last_error`. It is probably returning `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`

Comment: This doesn't appear to be valid JSON. It's a object with a repeated `items` key, so I expect that the output is not well defined. I think you were expecting the value of the `items` key to be an array, but it isn't. It throws errors anyway - e.g. http://codepad.viper-7.com/KIFqba *and* there is no `IF` statement per your question. So.... fix all of that stuff and come back :)

Comment: Replace the loop with `foreach($obj['items'] as &$item){echo $item['cID'],',';}` It should output `55,`.

Comment: @Hamish is correct, you can't repeat keys in JSON.

Comment: As a side note, you could use `foreach` once you have successfully decoded the json into an array, however - as mentioned already the json is bad, it will only provide you with the last item

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel changing the loop to a semantically equivalent alternative won't have any effect.

Comment: @Hamish Thank you, between you and Goran i got it working, i thought i needed 'items' at the beginning of each entry but now i see the correct format

Comment: @TimSeguine "semantically equivalent"? You should look 10 times to the code before commenting. You will see a huge difference.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I understand exactly what your code does. All you did was: 1) swap out a for loop for a foreach loop (looping over the items in this case by reference) 2) collapse the two echo statements into 1 using `,` . Neither of those things changes what the code actually does, and neither of those things changes the fact that the OP's code doesn't work because the JSON is malformed, which has nothing to do with the loop in the first place. It is purely a stylistic change and at best a micro-optimization to code that wasn't broken in the first place.

Comment: @TimSeguine The OP uses `$obj['items'][$i]['cID']`. That's 3 levels. The JSON that was presented (pretending it is valid) only has 2 levels. As you can see, I did more than simply a micro-optimization and `swap out a for loop for a foreach loop (looping over the items in this case by reference)`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel The difference in number of levels in the JSON data is irrelevant to how loops function in PHP. You are being ridiculous. The part you quoted from my comment is precisely (and all) what you did.

Comment: @TimSeguine Yes I am. I'm trying to explain something to you.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Here is a demo comparing your loop to mine: http://ideone.com/eDbbuQ They do exactly the same thing. Period. End of discussion. You are wrong. Thanks for Trying.

Comment: @TimSeguine The JSON is different...

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Of course it is different. It is what the OP meant to do. Look at the accepted solution. See the thing that actually fixed the OP's problem? That is the only change necessary to make the OP's code work. Your change is completely irrelevant. Like I have been trying to tell you for the past half an hour. IF you keep the original JSON they still do exactly the same thing, that is: *not work at all*.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel (Since you think that was an unreasonable change) Why would I include *known bad data* in an example? It would be complete nonsense. Reasoning about loop behavior on data we already know is corrupt is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have key "items" multiple time in your JSON which is wrong. Please note that JSON key must be unique for well formed JSON.

Basically there is no error if you use more than one key with the same name, but in JSON, the last key with the same name is the one that is gonna be used. In your case, the key "items" would be better to contain an array of objects as it's value:

```
{'items' : [{"cID":"63","qty":"2"}, {"cID":"52","qty":"1"}, {"..." : "..."}]}
```

Comment: thanks, your JSON format was perfect and now i see my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

As Hamish stated in his [`comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116498/struggling-to-understand-json-parsing-via-php#comment42735481_27116498), you can't have json as you've supplied. The keys (which is `items` in this case) are going to overwrite each other until the last key.
What I suggest is if you create an array like this:

```
{"items":[{"cID":"63","qty":"2"}, {"cID":"52","qty":"1"},.....]}
```

Allowing you to itterate as you require.
Meaning you can simply loop as you require:

```
$items = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($items as $thing){
    echo $thing['cID'];
    echo ",";
}
```

Comment: Your JSON is still invalid. You are opening `[` twice but closing only once.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Great Spot! Silly typo this early in the morning. Fixed it.

Comment: Don't worry dude, lets pretend we didn't see it and it didn't happened. Everybody makes mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been pointed out, your JSON data is malformed.

But since Stack Overflow is a rather inefficient method of syntax checking your data, I would suggest using a JSON linter (such as [this one](https://github.com/Seldaek/jsonlint)) on static JSON data in the future. Or at the very least, checking the return value of [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) after parsing to look for potential problems at least when testing or debugging.